# Shortest subsequence length for a given sum Memoized solution giving wrong answer

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

The Bruteforce approach to find the shortest subsequence length for a given sum is giving the correct 2,2,9 outputs for the inputs given in the main method but when memoized getting wrong output 3,3,9. Can anyone help with this please? Thanks.

```
class ShortestSubsequenceWithSum {    
  public static int shortestSubsequenceWithSum(int[] num, int s, int cnt, Integer []dp) {
    if(s == 0){
      return cnt;
    }
    if(s < 0){
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    if(dp[s] != null){
      return dp[s];
    }
    int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
      int rem = s - num[i];
      int ways = shortestSubsequenceWithSum(num, rem, cnt +1, dp);
      res = Math.min(res, ways);
      dp[s] = res;
    }
    // System.out.println("Returning value at @ " + s);
    return dp[s];
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] num = {1, 1, 2, 3};
    Integer dp[] = new Integer[5+1];
    System.out.println(shortestSubsequenceWithSum(num, 5,0, dp));
    num = new int[]{1, 2, 7, 1};
    dp = new Integer[9+1];
    System.out.println(shortestSubsequenceWithSum(num, 9,0, dp));
    num = new int[]{1};
    dp = new Integer[9+1];
    System.out.println(shortestSubsequenceWithSum(num, 9,0, dp));
  }
}
```

Comment: Are `Integer` arrays in java initialized to `null`?

Comment: Yes Integer arrays in java initialized to null. Added java tag.

Comment: There are a couple of things about your question that are unclear to me.  Firstly, can numbers be chosen from `nums` more than once?  (Your third test case suggests they can: it seems to form 9 by choosing the `1` 9 times.)  Secondly, can we choose numbers that are not consecutive in `numbers`?  E.g. in your first test case, can 4 be made up from 1 and 3 even though 1 and 3 aren't adjacent in {1, 1, 2, 3}?

Comment: Yes, it is unbounded knapsack, numbers can be chosen multiple times. Yes second understanding also correct, we can choose 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the way your recursive method works at present isn't amenable to memoization.

It looks like you are using your `dp` array to store the currently-known minimum count of numbers required to make a total.  So `dp[5]` will be the minimum count of numbers required to make a total of 5.  If `dp[5] = 3` then you have found a way to make a total of 5 from three numbers, but not yet found a way to make 5 from fewer than three numbers.

Your method `shortestSubsequenceWithSum` presently returns the minimum count of numbers required to reach the total plus the number of recursive calls currently made. If you want to use memoization you will have to adjust this method to return the minimum count of numbers required to reach the total, regardless of how many levels of recursion there have so far been.

The changes you will need to make are:

- In the handling for the case `s == 0`, return `0` rather than `cnt`.  This represents being able to make a total of 0 from zero numbers.
- Change the line `dp[s] = res` to `dp[s] = res + 1`.  `res` contains the (minimum) count of numbers that make up `s - num[i]` for each value of `i` so far, so we add 1 for choosing `num[i]` in a combination that adds up to `s`.

These should be enough to get your code working.  However, you can in fact move the line `dp[s] = res + 1` immediately outside the `for` loop: we may as well wait for the final value of `res` before assigning it to `dp[s]`. You can also remove the parameter `cnt` from your method `shortestSubsequenceWithSum`, and all the calls to this method, as this parameter isn't being used any more.

This should leave you with the following:

```java
    /**
     * Returns the minimum count of numbers from the given array that can
     * make up a total. The same number can be chosen multiple times.
     * @param num The numbers that can be chosen from.
     * @param s The total to reach.
     * @param dp An array that memoizes pre-computed values of this method.
     * @return The minimum count of numbers from 'num' that totals 's'.
     */
    public static int shortestSubsequenceWithSum(int[] num, int s, Integer []dp) {
        if(s == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(s < 0){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        if(dp[s] != null){
            return dp[s];
        }
        int res = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
            int rem = s - num[i];
            int ways = shortestSubsequenceWithSum(num, rem, dp);
            res = Math.min(res, ways);
        }
        dp[s] = res + 1;
        // System.out.println("Returning value at @ " + s);
        return dp[s];
    }
```

---

Finally, I'll note that this code does not handle the case that there are no combinations that add up to the total.  I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for you, see below for an example test case:

```java
int[] num = {2, 4, 6};
Integer dp[] = new Integer[5+1];
System.out.println(shortestSubsequenceWithSum(num, 5, dp));
```

Comment: Thank you Luke. If you can please tell where can I sharp my skill that is needed to tackle these types of issue, that will be great?

Comment: I guess some of this comes with experience.  Another thing to consider is writing unit tests. Start with tests for very small cases.  In this case, you could perhaps start with testing your method returns the correct value for a total of 0, a total of 1 where `nums` contains only 1, a total of 3 where `nums` contains only 1, a total of `3` where `nums` contains 1 and 2, and so on.  When things aren't working with recursive code, there's often a problem with a small case, and it's easier to debug small cases than larger cases.

Comment: Point noted. Thank you very much.